# Join between a sqlsever table and an oracle table

Tags: oracle, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have been using SQL Server 2008 for a short time now and have never used Oracle before. I am able to access an Oracle table through SQL Server with the syntax

```
select * from [OracleDB1]..[OracleDB1].[Zips]
```

(where OracleDB1 is the oracle database and Zips is the table I require)

Is it possible to join a SQL Server table with this one in a Table-valued Function? Just using a normal join as I would with SQL Server tables gives an **Invalid object name** error on the Oracle table.

Can this be done directly (or at all) or is it possible to do this some other way such as table variables?

example query:

```
select * from dbo.Table1 t INNER JOIN [OracleDB1]..[OracleDB1].[Zips] z where t.zip = z.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was performing the join wrong since I missed the ON clause. I was able to get it to work by declaring a temptable and joining on that.

```
declare @tempTable table{
    ZIP nvarchar(5),
    COUNTY nvarchar(10)
}
insert @tempTable select ZIP, COUNTY, from [OracleDB1]..[OracleDB1].[ZIPS]
select * from dbo.Table1 t INNER JOIN @tempTable z on t.ZIP = v.ZIP where t.AdmissionOn >= '08-08-2011' AND t.AdmissionOn <= ''09-08-2011'
```

This also worked in line as I had in the original question once I added the ON clause but the table variable suits my needs better since it only has to access the Oracle table once and not each comparison.